How to solve this Integral Equation that arises from Gauss's Law
I am interested in finding the electric field strength a distance $a/2$ (a>0) from an infinite line charge of uniform density $\lambda$. WLOG, let the line charge go through the origin in the $\hat{z} $ direction, and my point of interest be $(a/2, 0, 0)$. Now the standard approach would be to construct a gaussian cylinder of radius $a/2$, but instead, I would like to use a cube of side length a. Furthermore, I would like to limit my assumptions to the electric field being a central field in the xy plane (with no z component), and that the magnitude of the electric field $E(r)$ is differentiable with respect to r for r>0.
The flux ($\Phi$) through the face with center $(a/2,0,0)$ is
$$\Phi = \int \textbf{E} \cdot \hat{x} dA$$
$$=\int E(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dA$$
$$=a^2 \int_{0}^{a/2}E(\sqrt{y^2+(a/2)^2})\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+(a/2)^2}}dy$$
Now setting up gauss's law (and letting $u=\sqrt{y^2+(a/2)^2}$), I have arrived at the integral equation
$$4a^2 \int_{a/2}^{a\sqrt{2}/2}E(u)\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-(a/2)^2)}}du=\frac{a\lambda}{\varepsilon_0}$$
Or with the substitution $u=\frac{a}{2}sec(\theta)$
$$4a^2 \int_{0}^{\pi /4}E(\frac{a}{2}sec(\theta))sec(\theta)d\theta=\frac{a\lambda}{\varepsilon_0}$$
I know both of these equations are correct as I can let $E(r)$ take on the form $E(r)=kr^{-1}$ and both of these equations yield the correct result of
$$E(a/2)=\frac{\lambda}{\pi\varepsilon_0a}$$
However, I would like to solve either (I am not sure which is the easier form to work with) integral equations without making more physical assumptions about the behavior of the electric field. I have tried letting $E(r)$ taking on the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x-\frac{a}{2})^n$ to then integrate but I couldn't get a closed solution. I have also tried without success to Laplace and Fourier transform with Wolfram Alpha's help, but I believe the issue there is that in general the transform of 1/r fails to converge so I won't be able to solve in transformed space for a function that would transform back to the correct solution. Please help me with other techniques to preferably analytically solve the integral equations.

Replacing $a/2$ by $x$ and doing the change of variable $u=x/y$ you get the following multiplicative convolution
$$\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}^1 E(x/y)\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\frac{K}{x}$$ This is the multiplicative convolution between $E$ and the function $f(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}1_{[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1]}(y).$
You want to prove that $E(x)=K_1/x$ for some constant $K_1.$ For simplication consider $E_1(x)=xE(x)$ which satifies
$$g(x)=\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}^1 E_1(x/y)\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=K$$
and you want to prove that $E_1(x)=K_1.$ A way to do this is to consider $g'$
$$g'(x)=\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}^1 E'_1(x/y)\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}}=0$$ This says that the multiplicative convolution of $E_1'$ and $f$ is zero. To conclude from this that $E_1'$ is zero, one has to observe  that the Mellin transform of $f$, namely $$M_f(s)=\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}^1 y^{s-1}f(y)dy$$ is positive on $(0,\infty)$ (although not explicitely computable). Since
$$M_{E_1'*f}(s)=M_{E_1'}(s)\times M_f(s)=0$$ we get $M_{E_1'}(s)=0$ for all $s>0$ implying $E_1'(x)=0$ for all $x>0$ as desired.

Should the Mellin transform of f have f(y)dy instead of f(s)ds?

I have corrected, thanks.
